# AMAZON EC2 Find and Delete Images by ebs or ami id

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to read through the amazon docs for the ruby sdk. I'm trying to filter the list by ami-id and ebs id. I'm getting an error with my code and im not sure what im doing wrong. I'm not entirely sure how to delete them yet.

I attached a screen shot of the error I'm getting. Any help would be appriciated.

this is the var passed truncated numbers.[image]

ami-0000000

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:region)
puts ec2.describe_images(:image_id => ebs)
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer.

```
images = ec2.describe_images(
                          image_ids: [ebs,],
                        )
```